# Can I count how many kinds enum_class could be?

Tags: c++

```
enum class COLOR_ : char
{
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
    YELLOW
};
int monsternum{ kinds_of_COLOR_*3 };
```

my enum class `COLOR_` may change a lot, during this project.
I want `monsternum` must be +3 for each kind of `COLOR_` how can I know the number of enum_class's kinds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `enum` is indexed from `0` up to `n-1` (where `n` is the number you want), the idiom I've seen used in the past is to include the count as an "extra" enum value.

```
enum class COLOR_ : char
{
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
    YELLOW,
    COUNT
};
```

Then you can get it and simply cast to an `int` explicitly.

```
int monsternum{ (int)(COLOR_::COUNT)*3 };
```

If you add any colors above `COUNT`, then `COUNT` will have its index changed accordingly.

Comment: that way sounds easy and fun to use. thank u.  : )